# nginx configuration - route to root path dynamically

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do here... But in short, when i go to:

http://url/user, I want nginx to load from /dir/user/www/.
In essence, dynamically route that http://url/$user/...  to /dir/$user/www/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**alias**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) to redirect a request to a particular folder.

Defines a replacement for the specified location. For example, with the following configuration

```
location /i/ {
    alias /data/w3/images/;
}
```

on request of “/i/top.gif”, the file /data/w3/images/top.gif will be sent.

**Example:**

```
location /valdeir {
    alias /var/www/html/user1;
}

location /psr {
    alias /var/www/html/user2;
}

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}
```